# react native touch id is not working in real device

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am using react-native-touch-id to enable the Biometric auth in my project but its not working in real device. I added key and description in info.plist also follow all the steps which is mentioned in official docs of library, if anyone is familiar please help

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {BackHandler, StatusBar, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {SafeAreaView} from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import TouchID from 'react-native-touch-id';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';P
import RouteHome from './src/navigation';
import store from './src/redux/store';

export default function App() {
  const [isAuth, setIsAuth] = useState(false);

  const optionalConfigObject = {
    title: 'Authentication Required', 
    imageColor: '#e00606', 
    imageErrorColor: '#ff0000', 
    sensorDescription: 'Touch sensor', 
    sensorErrorDescription: 'Failed', 
    cancelText: 'Cancel', 
    fallbackLabel: 'Show Passcode', 
    unifiedErrors: false, 
    passcodeFallback: false,
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    handleBiometric();
  });
  const handleBiometric = () => {
    TouchID.isSupported(optionalConfigObject).then(biometryType => {
      if (biometryType === 'FaceID') {
        console.log('FaceID is supported.');
      } else {
        if(isAuth) {
          return null;
        }
        TouchID.authenticate('', optionalConfigObject).then((success) => {
          setIsAuth(success)
        }).catch((err) => {
          BackHandler.exitApp();
        })
      }
    });
  };
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <SafeAreaView>
        <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" />
        <RouteHome />
      </SafeAreaView>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: what do you mean not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check documentation for this library it says - it is not supported https://github.com/naoufal/react-native-touch-id and better to use another solutions like https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/sdk-47/packages/expo-local-authentication.

Good manual is here: https://blog.logrocket.com/implementing-react-native-biometric-authentication-expo/